# Adding libcurl to Code::Blocks IDE on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: curl, codeblocks, libcurl

I have a problem with addinng libcurl to Code Blocks. I've installed curl on ubuntu ($ sudo apt-get install curl), but i don't know how to implement it. In linker settings I've added file libcurl.a. Program ( in C) does not compile.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I've read many tutorials today and spend couple of hours.Still nothing so i went back to starting point. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: 1. You should install the libcurl-dev package first when developing with libcurl 2. You should show exactly what happens when you try to compile when you ask for help like this.

Comment: I got massive amount of errors. https://imgur.com/admtRhf. Here's some of them.

Comment: Right, so you chose to link with the static lib so then you need to provide all dependencies manually as well. I suggest you link with -lcurl to use the shared version which will spare you a lot of linking pain.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly I have to do ?

Comment: Read up on what linking is and how it works, and what static and shared libraries are and how they differ. Then you'll view this question and the answers in an entirely different light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install curl` installs the curl commandline tool and the libcurl shared library.
It does not install the header files for curl development (`curl.h` etc.) and it does not install
the static library, `libcurl.a`, to which you are trying to link.

You will find it much more convenient to link to the shared library, `libcurl.so`

- At the console prompt run `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` (to install the curl development headers).
- In the C::B IDE:

  - Remove `libcurl.a` from **Linker settings**.
  - In the **Linker settings** -> **Other linker options**, enter `-lcurl` (instructing the linker to link `libcurl.so`) and OK out.

Then rebuild the example program.

Comment: @davoid You're welcome. If you think that this answer is correct you can help the SO community by marking it *accepted*. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/196691. You will also get some reputation points for accepting the answer and so will I.

Comment: I still have a problem with this library. Here's an error: curl/types.h: No such file or directory. Everything else is working fine. For instance curl/easy.h is working ok.|

Comment: @davoid `curl/types.h` is deprecated and was removed from the package in 2011. See the resolution of this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=636457. Either you do not need this header or the code that requires it is out of date.